# Trying to pipx install Brownie without installing MS Visual C++

Tags: python, c++, pip, bitarray, brownie

I'm currently trying to install Brownie for Python on my Windows machine using pipx:

`pipx install eth-brownie`.

When I run this command, there is a "fatal error" message saying:

`pip failed to build packages: bitarray cytoolz lru-dict`

I also get a "possibly relevant" error message:

`Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

I was wondering if anyone knew of a workaround to solve this that did not involve downloading MS Visual Studio. If not, its not a fatal blow to the project I'm working on, I would just like to save storage. Thanks.

Comment: The Build Tools are not Visual Studio, but the compiler tools without the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip failed to build packages: bitarray cytoolz lru-dict
```

[`bitarray` PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) regarding installation states

> If you have a working C compiler, you can simply:
>
> `$ pip install bitarray`
>
> If you rather want to use precompiled binaries, you can:
>
> - `conda install bitarray` (both the default Anaconda repository as well as conda-forge support bitarray)
> - download Windows wheels from [Chris Gohlke](https://pypi.org/project/cytoolz/)

So you might try installing using .whl file, if you are able to find suitable .whl for your system and architecture in linked site, however

[`cytoolz` PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/cytoolz/) regarding dependencies states

> `cytoolz` supports Python 3.5+ with a common codebase. It is developed
> in Cython, but requires no dependecies other than CPython and a C
> compiler. Like `toolz`, it is a light weight dependency.

So I suppose you would need working C compiler anyway.